# What is the best practice to set variables for session in symfony?

Tags: php, session, symfony

Good day to all. What syntax is more appropriate to use it in controller Symfony 3?

**Case #1:**

`$request->getSession()->set('secret_token', $current_user_token);`

**OR**

**Case #2:**

`$_SESSION['secret_token']=current_user_token;`

And if i will use case #2 what problems i can face?

Comment: If you are using symfony, case 1 is what you should use. [Symfony tracks things with an internal mechanism.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.php#L93)

Comment: Read the Symfony documentation is the best pratice to avoid questions like this.